# OpenCV VideoCapture will failed after a while?

Tags: opencv

I use VideoCapture to get images of **multiple RTMP streams**.

At first it worked very well, but after a while it returned and failed without any exceptions, just print `Read stream.name picture failed!`. I don’t know if the problem is caused by the buffer being full.

The phenomenon is that if the time interval for reading is short enough, it can work all the time, if the time interval for reading is long, then it stops working after a period of time.

Below is the code without sleep, **if I add a sleep in the loop then it stops working after a period of time**

```
  def process(self):
    while True:
      // 1. get streams info like url etc.
      streams = self.stream_manager.get()
      for stream in streams:
        t_start = time.time()
        // 2. I will buffer the capture to avoid create every time
        capture = self.buffer.get(stream.name)
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if not ret:
          print("Read {} picture failed! ".format(stream.name))
        else:
          if self.image_queue.full():
            self.image_queue.get_nowait()
          self.image_queue.put((stream.name, frame))
          print("{} read success cost: {}".format(stream.name, time.time() - t_start))
    // time.sleep(0.1)  // which cause the failed
```

Comment: Try to use cv2.waitKey(100)

Comment: I want to contiue reader from the stream, waitKey will work?

Comment: waitKey blocks the thread if it is "waitKey(0)" in other case it waits for written milliseconds.

Comment: My question is why this phenomenon occurs instead of joining the wait

Comment: It seems to be an opencv bug. Some googling brings an opinion that if you run opencv code in subprocess it works fine with *time.sleep*